# How to change to array of object values in angular js html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

My array of objects:

```js
MyCart = {
  cartID: "cart101",
  listProducts : [
      {pid:101, pname:"apple", price: 200, qty:3},
      {pid:102, pname:"banana", price: 100, qty:12}
   ]
}
```

I displayed in HTML form update qty in get data and update values to send server

How would I update an array of object values in Angular/HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two way data binding with ngmodel form attribute:

**app.component.html**

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
  <div *ngFor="let x of data; let i = index">
     <input name="qty" [(ngModel)]="data?.listProducts[i]?.qty">
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app.component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  data = {
     cartID: "cart101",
     listProducts : [
         {pid:101, pname:"apple", price: 200, qty:3},
         {pid:102, pname:"banana", price: 100, qty:12}
     ]
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() { 
    // logic for sending this.data to backend server
  }
}
```